# C: multiple child process each generate different random number

Tags: c, random, fork, child-process, srand

I am trying to let children to process different random value EVERYTIME. If there is 3 children, I want them to generate 3 different random value  each, so in total 3*3=9 different number. I've tried many `srand()`, if I go `srand(time(NULL))` , all the children produces three same random number`(123, 123, 123)`, and if I put `getpid()` into `srand()`, each child produces a random number three times`(111,222,333)`. But I can't find something that produces 9 different random values. Here are my codes.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  int pid[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            printf("Fork Failed\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        if (pid[i] == 0) {
            time_t t;
            srand((int)time(&t) % getpid());
            int r = rand() % 30;
            int count = 0;
            while (count < 3){
                printf("Child %d: %d\n",i+1,r);
                count++;
            }
            exit(0);
        }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call `rand()` once in each child (outside the `while (count < 3)` loop, and then you print out that same number three times in a loop.  Note that you do not assign any new value to `r` between loop iterations, so naturally its value hasn't changed when you print it again.

If you want three different numbers, call `rand()` three times (inside the loop).  Replace

```
        int r = rand() % 30;
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 3){
            printf("Child %d: %d\n",i+1,r);
            count++;
        }
```

with

```
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 3){
            int r = rand() % 30;
            printf("Child %d: %d\n",i+1,r);
            count++;
        }
```